# Dimensional Analysis Does Not Check Out

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, dimensional-analysis, oscillators

I'm looking over the lecture notes found [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-03sc-physics-iii-vibrations-and-waves-fall-2016/resources/mit8_03scf16_lec3/), and if you scroll down to the end of page 2, the writers make the statement $ A(\omega _d) = \dfrac{f_0}{\sqrt{\omega_0^2 - \omega_d^2 + \omega_d^2\Gamma^2}}$ The math that leads to this point checks out, but unfortunately the units don't. The problem is that $\omega _d$ and $\omega _0$ have units of $T^{-1}$, but $\Gamma$ has units of $T^{-1}L^{-1}$. Therefore, the quantity $\omega_0^2 - \omega_d^2 + \omega_d^2\Gamma^2$ shouldn't exist, as it is adding two different measurements with different units.

Comment: $\Gamma$ has dimensions of inverse time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely there is a small error in the notes.

From context, it seems to me the equation should be:

$$A(\omega _d) = \dfrac{f_0}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2 - \omega_d^2)^2 + \omega_d^2\Gamma^2}}$$

It is a great skill to be able to sanity-check expressions using dimensional analysis, as you've done here.